# Could there be any way to enable unsupported fingerprint reader in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04

I have a Hp 13-ah0002la laptop with a fingerprint reader, I understand that ubuntu 22.04 already comes with support for fingerprints, however using `lsusb` I realize that it does not recognize my device, is there a driver or library that can make ubuntu recognize my fingerprint device?

Comment: Great question for HP support: Does that particular fingerprint reader have a Linux module?

Comment: Same with the latest Thinkpads. Vendors won't tell, so you either have to wait for someone to reverse engineer it, or you'll do it yourself....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I looked on several sites and could not find which fingerprint reader your laptop has. I have an Envy CE1000n with a synaptics FP reader and can't find any drivers for it either. Synaptics does not make drivers for Linux kernels, nor does HP, so we ( the Linux users ) have to do this on our own. I checked newer kernels, but they don't support mine. Can you inform the community which FP reader your device has. It could be different than mine, so it could be supported.